# Сумма списка столбца pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть база и необходимо посчитать общею площадь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
app = app.dropna()
app["Площадь"] = app["Площадь"].str.replace("[?]","0")
app["Площадь"] = app["Площадь"].str.split("/")
#app["Площадь"] = pd.to_numeric(app["Площадь"], errors='coerce')
#app = app["Площадь"].map(sum, pd.to_numeric(app["Площадь"]))


app.head().dtypes
```

И вот не могу понять как это сделать...

Comment: В приведённых вами данных в площади нет ни вопросов ни дроби. Приведите все варианты данных в этом поле. А так то ну откусите первый и последний символ, потом разбейте по запятой и от первой компоненты возьмите float. Но нужно проверять если точек в строке не одна, то там дата, а не площадь (последняя строка выборки).

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)